# Closed: 'How do window curtains' blowing and waves breaking on a beach, insinuate sex?'

Tags: discussion

Why was [How do window curtains' blowing and waves breaking on a beach, insinuate sex?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/76176/13434) closed as unclear?

Comment: I didn't have anything to do with that vote... but perhaps it's because the question doesn't make much sense. The curtains and the waves are examples of an ellipsis... leaving something out (usually intentionally)... the paragraph goes on to explain why. It's not that the curtains **themselves** are sexy, it's that they're inserted immediately after actions that imply that sex is about to happen/is happening. This is a common trope in both film, TV and even in books. It's so common that it's likely we just know what it means and so your question makes no sense.

Comment: Please remember, when you ask questions, you need to do more than post one line of text and a huge quote box. Format your question in a way to be more explicit what you're trying to understand... explain what you need help with. Two sentences is rarely enough.

Comment: I seen this question, before; when did it turn into a wall of text?

Answer (score 6):

Currently, the wording isn't very clear on what you're asking.  Are you asking WHY those two scenes were used?  Are you asking about the history of such imagery in cinema to represent intercourse?  Also, the quote you provided basically answers both of those questions, so it's confusing as to what you're really after.

Comment: I abridge the sentence in my post to try to simplify: 'Were the choices [...] to insinuate sex random [...]? If not, how can these physical acts be interpreted as erotic?'

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal Explaining the question **here** is useless. You need to *edit* your actual question to make it clear. As long as it sits, unedited, it's never going to get reopened.